# Read WFS Service data

Tags: service, web-feature-service

I have searched for this but not able to get clear instruction to extract data from an WFS data. I have seen the schema but i am not sure how to call these in C# code.

I want to be able to consume the data and extract the XML and read the XML data to get some fields. But there is no clear approach for this available.

Any sample code would help. I would like to refrain from using any libraries and would like to use only standard inbuilt libraries.

Thanks.
Shankar

Answer (score 0):

I, too, am at the beginning of the WFS journey.  So welcome!  Some of the resources I have been looking at are:

- https://www.ogc.org/standards/wfs - Here you can look at the standard specification, etc.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service - Basic WFS information and links
- https://www.weather.gov/mdl/webservices_wfs - United States National Weather Service - WFS Information
- https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap - SharpMap.Net Library for requesting data from WFS services

Good luck.  If you find a link with good info, please post it here.

-Joe